# How to compare date and time differently in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm getting date and time from my customer side using laravel. How can we compare given date and time with database and return result to customer?

For Example, if I am getting Date and time from customer and I want to show him rows which do not clash with his date and time.

Comment: Do you mean you want to check for rows where either the date or the time match user input? So that 03/10/2015 12:00:00 will return any rows with date as 03/10/2015 or time is 12:00? An example would really be helpful

Comment: example: customer is giving me date and  time to book his place(or table) for particular date and time. and i want check whether 2 hours before and 2 hours after with respect to given time table or place is booked or not? if 2 hours before and 2 hours after if there is any entry i found then i will not allow him to book that table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you can do all of this in a DB query:

```
$date = '2015-03-11 06:29:56';
$alreadyBooked = DB::table('bookings')
                   ->whereRaw('ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, datetime, ?)) <= 120', [$date])
                   ->exists();

if($alreadyBooked){
    // show error
}
```

#### Explanation

`?` is a placeholder for the `$date`. Those are called bindings and are mostly used to get a clean query and prevent SQL injection.

`TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, ...` will return the difference of the input date time and the one stored in the database field in minutes. If that value is smaller or equal to 120 (2 hours = 120 minutes) it matches the condition.

`ABS` will make the value "unsigned". `-60` becomes `60`

Comment: I tried your code but it is giving me error:    SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `table_booking_log` where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time, -120) between 120 and ?)

Comment: Can you double check that you got the parentheses right?

Comment: i have copy pasted your code just changed my table name. still i am getting the same error.

Comment: what "?" means in your query. actually i am not getting your code. can you please tell me meaning of your code.

Comment: I've corrected/improved the query and added an explanation. Take a look

Comment: Go to my stackoverflow profile and then visit my website. My email is on there...

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel you can use Carbon for comparing date/time

**Example**

```
$start = new Carbon\Carbon('2014-01-05 12:00:00');
$end = new Carbon\Carbon('2014-01-01 12:00:00');
echo $end->diffInDays($start);
```

Or you can directly compare date from db

```
$customer =App\Customer::first();
$start = $customer->db_date_column;
$end = new Carbon\Carbon('2014-01-01 12:00:00');
echo $end->diffInDays($start);
```

More information http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

**Update** 
 if you want the time diff in hour, you can use this `$end-diffInHours($start);` instead.

Comment: mininoz how will i send dynamic values to that new Carbon\Carbon('2014-01-05 12:00:00'); function? i want to store values coming from customer in variable and then want to send it to Carbon. Help

Comment: @ParagBhingre If I understand correctly, user will submit a form with request booking date. Therefore you can get the date from that. but don't forget the correct the date format before send it to the function.

Comment: i want time difference  for that particular date.

Comment: @ParagBhingre where do you get the particular date from?

Comment: i am getting date and time from customer.i just need to check for that date and time any entry is available in database or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

in Laravel just donot forget to add this:

```
use DateTime;
```

the other option is you can use SQL, look at my sample:

```
      return DB::table('corporation')->join('corporation_subscription','corporation.id','=','corporation_subscription.corp_id')
        ->where('corporation.id','=',$id)
        ->where('corporation_subscription.period','>=',DB::raw('DATEDIFF(NOW(),corporation_subscription.created_at)'))
        ->where('corporation_subscription.status','!=', 'cancel' )
        ->get();
```

this will help you too : `DB::raw('DATEDIFF(NOW(),corporation_subscription.created_at)'))`

Comment: Actually i want Mainly time Difference.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: echo $interval->format('%R%a days'); here can u tell me the format to show difference in time.%a is showing difference in days.